# How to add different arraylist variables together into a single variable in a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

So I have a list of doubles that I am trying to add up. I am rather new to Java so this might be a dumb question: how do I return the arraylist's doubles together in a single variable? Any help is appreciated :)

```
public double totalVolume(){
  double volume = 0;
  if (cList.size() != 0) {
     volume = cList.get(0).volume();
  }
  else {
     return 0;
  }

  int indexVolume = 0;

  while (indexVolume < cList.size()) {
     if (!(indexVolume < cList.get(indexVolume).volume())) {
        volume = cList.get(indexVolume).volume();
     }
     // how do I take volume and add it to itself after each while loop?
     indexVolume++;
  }

  return volume;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to keep a running total?

You could just type this:

```
volume = volume + cList.get(indexVolume).volume();
```

or, shorter,

```
volume += cList.get(indexVolume).volume();
```